# Make vertical ul li > sub-menu : go-upwards when browser screen is over

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, media-queries, navigationbar

The problem is that when I hover to first-main-menu the sub-menu gets hidden under the screen of browsers, I want that the sub-menu should goes upwards when touches bottom of the browser else the sub-menu stays on-screen it should float down.

Note: if possible this problem should solved with pure CSS or a media query.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7JFR.png)

Comment: you should add height:100 vh for parent div and add overflow:auto

Comment: @Ranjithv Thanks for the answer but the parent class already has overflow: auto & height: 100vh. Kindly check-out this link { https://vertical-nav.bss.design/ }. 

The problem is that "I want that the user should not scroll to view the sub-menu when it touches the bottom of the browser".
It should detect the bottom of the browser for current active nav-item and its sub-menu should go upwards.